# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined angular 4 (NOT DUPLICATE)

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error `LeaderBoardComponent.html:27 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

The error is in the HTML:

`<div *ngIf="leaderBoardTableData.length > 0">`

In the component I have:

```
export class LeaderBoardComponent implements OnInit {
    leaderBoardTableData: Array<LeaderBoardModel>;
    constructor(private leaderBoardService: LeaderBoardService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscribeLeaderBoardDataFromStore();
    }

    subscribeLeaderBoardDataFromStore() {
        this.leaderBoardService.getLeaderBoard()
            .skipWhile((data) => { return _.isEmpty(data) })
            .subscribe((data) => {
                if (!_.isEmpty(data)) {
                    this.leaderBoardTableData = [data];
                }
            });
    }
```

and the service:

```
getLeaderBoard(): Observable<LeaderBoardModel> {
        return this.httpUtil.get(this.appConstants.END_POINT_LEADERBOARD)
            .map(response => <LeaderBoardModel>response.json());
    }
```

When I tried to do the following:

`hello 1 <div *ngIf="leaderBoardTableData.length > 0"> hello 2`
Only `hello 1` printed and I got the error.

Comment: `leaderBoardTableData` is undefined until your `subscribe` resolves.

Comment: @crashmstr that was I was thinking, it is not being initialized. How can I resolve that?

Comment: Add a test to see if it is not undefined before checking `.length`? You'll need to get used to the asynchronous way things tend to work and having to wait on data.

Comment: try`<LeaderBoardModel[]>response.json()` instead of `<LeaderBoardModel>response.json()` and let me know.

Comment: Yes this does get rid of the error but now I get an error saying:`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'student' of undefined` from `<div class='rank-index'>{{leader.leaderboard.student.studentLevel‌​}}</div>` which is in a loop `<div *ngFor="let leader of leaderBoardTableData;`

Answer (score 2):

This error will occur if `leaderBoardTableData` is not defined. The easiest way to fix it is with the following:

```
<div *ngIf="leaderBoardTableData?.length > 0">
```

Note: you can use the `?.` operator inside html templates, but not in code itself.

Comment: Yes this does get rid of the error but now I get an error saying:`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'student' of undefined` from `<div class='rank-index'>{{leader.leaderboard.student.studentLevel}}</div>` which is in a loop `<div *ngFor="let leader of leaderBoardTableData;`

Comment: This is really just another occurrence of the same issue. Using `x?.y` operator only attempts to access property y if object x exists. So you could solve by using `leader.leaderboard?.student?.studentLevel` although just to be safe I would use `leader?.leaderboard?.student?.studentLevel`

Answer (score 0):

It's because the variable does not have value to solve it:

**Opcion 1**
You can inicialize it in the constructor:

```
constructor(){
   leaderBoardTableData = [];
}
```

**Opcion 2**
You can add a div with an if condition

```
<div *ngIf="leaderBoardTableData">
   <div *ngIf="leaderBoardTableData.length > 0">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this does get rid of the error but now I get an error saying:`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'student' of undefined` from `<div class='rank-index'>{{leader.leaderboard.student.studentLevel‌​}}</div>` which is in a loop `<div *ngFor="let leader of leaderBoardTableData;`

Comment: Each item of leaderBoardTableData has "leaderboard" property ? If it does not have the property will not work.